# crear un pdf de un div especifico con jspdf

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, jspdf

Cuando intento crear un pdf con `jsPdf` no me puede tomar el `div` especifico, he intentado de todo pero no me deja, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('ready', function(){
        $('.buttonNext').on('click', function(){
            var contenido = '';


            contenido += '<b>Moderador:</b>' + $('#nombre').val();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido +='<b>Tipo de Reunion:</b> ' + $('#tipoReunion option:selected').text();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<b>Descripcion:</b>' + $('#descrp').val();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido +='<b>Estado de Reunion:</b> ' + $('#estadoReunion option:selected').text();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido +='<b>Empresa:</b> ' + $('#SPT1Empresa option:selected').text();
            contenido += '<br>';

            contenido += '<b>Fecha de Realizacion:</b> ' + $('#birthday').val();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<b>Nombre tema:</b> ' + $('#tema option:selected').text();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<b>Nombre párrafo:</b> ' + $('#parr option:selected').text();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<b>Extracto:</b> ' + $('#extracto').text();
            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<b>Preguntas seleccionadas:</b> ' + $('#tblPregunta2 ').each(function(){
                $(this).find('td').each(function(){


                })


            });

            contenido += '<br>';
            contenido += '<button id="cmd1">generate PDF</button>';
            contenido += '<p><a href="pdf.php">Ver tabla en PDF</a></p>';

            $('#resumenContent').html(contenido);
        });
    });



</script>







<!-- End teban -->

<script src="jsPDF-master/jspdf.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF-master/plugins/standard_fonts_metrics.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF-master/plugins/split_text_to_size.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF-master/plugins/from_html.js"></script>
<script src="jsPDF-master/FileSaver.js"></script>


<title></title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            var doc = new jsPDF();
            var specialElementHandlers = {
                '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
                    return true;
                }
            };

            $('#cmd1').click(function () {
                doc.fromHTML($('#resumenContent').html(), 15, 15, {
                    'width': 170,
                    'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
                });
                doc.save('Usec.pdf');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
   <div id="step-4">
                                    <h2 class="StepTitle">Paso 4 Resumen</h2>
                                    <div id="resumenContent">

                                    </div>

                                    <div id="editor"></div>


                            </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

La mejor forma para convertir un `div` en PDF es la siguiente:

1.Añadir el siguiente `script` de `jsPdf` en el `<head>` del documento:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

2.Añadir el `script` para convertir a PDF

```
<script>
    function pruebaDivAPdf() {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
        source = $('#imprimir')[0];

        specialElementHandlers = {
            '#bypassme': function (element, renderer) {
                return true
            }
        };
        margins = {
            top: 80,
            bottom: 60,
            left: 40,
            width: 522
        };

        pdf.fromHTML(
            source, 
            margins.left, // x coord
            margins.top, { // y coord
                'width': margins.width, 
                'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
            },

            function (dispose) {
                pdf.save('Prueba.pdf');
            }, margins
        );
    }
</script>
```

3.Añadir tu contenido del HTML

```
<a href="javascript:pruebaDivAPdf()" class="button">Pasar a PDF</a>
<div id="imprimir">
    <h1>  
        Esto es un DIV impreso en PDF
    </h1>
</div>
```

**NOTA**: No olvides añadir también el archivo `js` del ***JQuery***

[Referencia al tutorial original](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf)

Comment: a mi me pasa algo extraño, estoy obteniendo todo el HTML que está dentro de un DIV pero solo me genera 1 hoja del pdf... ¿como genero más hojas según el contenido? 

:(

Comment: Funciona perfectamente. Gracias! Mi duda es si se puede hacer que el HTML ocupe un tamaño proporcional. Es decir, ahora mismo por ejemplo intento imprimir una tabla, y la imprimo sin problemas (gracias por el script), pero no me sale completa, porque ocupa más ancho que un folio. ¿Se podría hacer proporcional al tamaño del folio de alguna forma? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para resolver este problema, usé Html2Canvas Así que solo Agregar HTML2Canvas JS y luego use pdf.addHTML () en lugar de pdf.fromHTML () .

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');
 pdf.addHTML($('#ElementYouWantToConvertToPdf')[0], function () {
     pdf.save('Test.pdf');
 });
```